# Trying to search the contents of all txt files in a directory for a string and when found post the path to the file in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of search terms in range E3:E47. I want the macro to search all text files in a directory for the value of each cell, if the string is found I want it to report the file path to the equivalent K column.

I have this code, which runs but does nothing.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim theString As String
Dim path As String
Dim StrFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim file As TextStream
Dim line As String
Dim cel As Range
Dim Result As Range

Set rng = Application.Range("Sheet1!E3:E47")
path = Range("O1").Value
Result = Range("K3")
StrFile = Dir(path)


For Each cel In rng.Cells
    With cel

    theString = Result.Value
    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)
    Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
        line = file.ReadLine
        If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            StrFile = Result
            Result = Result.Offset(0, 1)
        Else
            Result.Value = "Nothing Found"
            Result = Result.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Loop
    End With
Next cel


End Sub
```

Comment: hi. u arent looping the files returned by dir. need a outer loop for this and u are crashing the var StrFile when u set it igual to Result. get a new var

Comment: There are tools out there that do this (i.e. grepwin). Can you not use them?